# how to set default screen brightness in fedora 17

Tags: linux, fedora

In fedora 16, I use "dconf-editor" to set the default color.
however, I couldn't find "ac-brightness" in the "dconf-editor".
I mean set the brightness when I start up my computer.

Comment: This is not programming related and should not be asked on [so] (see [faq#questions]). Try [su].

Comment: @ShawnChin: Flagged it to be migrated.

Answer (score 1):

There's an [open defect](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=695087) about this problem.  As far as I can tell the required settings are simply non-existent in F17.  As a work-around you can try [this script](https://github.com/ishanthilina/setBrightness).